# @MockBean injected into a constructor-autowired component

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, mockito, spring-boot-test, mockk

From the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html):

> When registered by type, any existing single bean of a matching type (including subclasses) in the context will be replaced by the mock

What if the service under test is autowired in the constructor, though? E.g. in Kotlin (I suppose `@MockkBean` and `@MockBean` work the same regarding DI):

```kotlin
 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
 class ExampleTests @Autowired constructor(val userOfService: UserOfService) {

   @MockkBean
   private lateinit var service: ExampleService

   ...
}
```

I would expect this example to fail because in order to instantiate `ExampleTests` Spring has to first obtain a proper instance of `UserOfService`. That shouldn't be possible at that time, though, because there's no bean of type `ExampleService` in the application context yet.

Contrary to my expectation, this works. How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you miss the other part from the documentation :

> In either case, if no existing bean is defined a new one will be
> added.

So `@MockBean` will also instantiate a bean automatically if that bean is not found in the spring context.

The sequence of actions are mainly as follows :

1. Start up the spring context which create all the spring `BeanDefinition` only that are registered in the spring context.
2. Process `@MockBean` which will replace the `BeanDefinition` in (1) or create a new `BeanDefinition`
3. Actually instantiate all the beans based on these `BeanDefinition`. It will handle which bean to be actually instantiated first and later.
4. Create a test instance (i.e ExampleTests) to execute its test methods. If any beans required to be auto-wired into the test instance are not created , it will fail.

So as long as you define `UserOfService` bean , `ExampleTests` can be instantiated as you are now using `@MockBean` on the `ExampleService` which means it must exist no matter you define it or not in the spring context for the test.

Comment: Yes, I read that part. The question perhaps is more about the timing, i.e. when exactly is the `@MockkBean` declaration processed, i.e. when is it registered to the application context? I would say as part of the `ExampleTests` instantiation but only _after_ the constructor arguments instantiation. If this was true then `UserOfService` couldn't be instantiated because `ExampleService` has not yet been. What's wrong with this argument?

Comment: @DavidKubecka. it is because`@MockkBean` will be processed before instantiate `ExampleTests` .I have updated my answer .please check

Comment: I don't understand how Spring can complete step 1 (instantiating all beans) without the required dependency `ExampleService` which is created only in step 2.

Comment: I must be missing some "obvious" piece of information regarding the inner workings of Spring DI mechanism :-)

Comment: @DavidKubecka , ok i add more details about it . please see my updated answer to see if it make sense. You can think that `BeanDefinition` is just some metadata about the beans. Spring will collect all of the `BeanDefinition` first and then actually create the bean instance after that. So when it comes to create the actual instance , it can have information to know which bean to create first from the  `BeanDefinition` 's info

Comment: Yes, now it makes more sense. One last question if you don't mind: What's exactly the way how `@MockkBean` is processed? I mean it's inside the class body and it's not static so it should be available only on a class instance. But that can't be created yet because of the incomplete dependency. Surely, there must be a different mechanism...

Comment: under the cover , it uses java reflection to access `@Mockbean` information. It does not need to create an instance in order to access it . It simply access it from the class instance (I.e `ExampleTests.class` )